# Share user folders between Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I've installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my notebook. I want to share the user folders:

- Pictures
- Musics
- Videos
- Downloads
- etc...

In my instalation I've 3 partitions:

- Windows 7
- Ubuntu
- Data

I already have setted the Windows 7 folders on partition `Data`. But is so hard change the Ubuntu folders.

I tried change paths with:

```
gedit .config/user-dirs.dirs
```

I.E.:

```
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/media/user/Dada/Pictures"
```

But everytime when I restart, the value changes to `"$HOME/"`

**How can I change path of user folders of Ubuntu and add to menu `Locals` on file explorer?**

Comment: I'd try rather to experiment with soft/hard linking your user folders (Pictures, Musics, Videos, Downloads, ...) from both OS'es to your Data partition.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to link the two systems in the folders of Data partition.

Comment: Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/questions/48446/how-to-make-permanent-change-to-config-user-dirs-dirs ?